# How to link the function to the HTML button and textfield in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am asked to create a web page that user inserts the age and get some message. If the user is under 21, send to disney.com. I do not know how to send. That is so far what I did. I am not sure the function is correct or not and the HTML button and textfield are not working if I insert the age and click.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>check is over 21 or not</title>
        <script>
        function CalAge(birthDateString) {
            var today = new Date();
            var birthDate = new Date(birthDateString);
            var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
            var month = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
            if (month < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                age--;
            }
            return age;
        }
        if(CalAge() >= 21) {
            alert("You are over 21!");
        } 
        if(CalAge() < 21) {
            alert("You are under 21!");
        }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body >
        <input type="text" name="age" size="30" onClick="Calage()" placeholder="Enter your age" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" onclick="CalAge()" value="SUBMIT Age">
        <input type="reset" onclick="CalAge()" value="Reset age">

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to redirect someone to a different website?

Comment: Yes, I also want to know when I insert my date of birth, I can get the message if I am order than 21.  If I am younger than 21, redirect to disney.com. But the HTML textfield and button do not work. Could you help me base on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to help you ...

```js
const ageInput = document.querySelector('#age-input');
ageInput.valueAsDate = new Date(); 

document.querySelector('#Bt-Submit').onclick = function()
{
  let Age = new Date( new Date() - ageInput.valueAsDate ).getFullYear() - 1970;
  console.log(Age);
  if (  Age < 21 ) { document.location.href = "https://disney.com" }
}
document.querySelector('#Bt-Reset').onclick = function()
{
  ageInput.valueAsDate = new Date(); 
}
```

```html
<label>birth date :
<input type="date" id="age-input" size="30"  />
</label>
<br />
<button id="Bt-Submit">SUBMIT Age</button>
<button id="Bt-Reset">Reset Age</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user is entering their age (not their birthday) then there's no need to calculate age. You could do something like this:

```js
const btnCalcAge = document.querySelector('#btn-calc-age');
const btnReset = document.querySelector('#btn-reset');
const txtAge = document.querySelector('#txt-age');
const MIN_AGE = 21;
btnCalcAge.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const age = parseInt(txtAge.value, 10);
  if (age < MIN_AGE) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.disney.com';
    return;
  }
  console.log('Welcome adult!');
});
btnReset.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  txtAge.value = "";
});
```

```html
<input id="txt-age" type="text" name="age" size="30" placeholder="Enter your age" />
<br />
<input id="btn-calc-age" type="button" value="SUBMIT Age" />
<input id="btn-reset" type="reset" value="Reset age" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a redirect technique. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004) perfectly describes how to redirect to another link using JavaScript.
As mentioned in the answer above you could redirect using any of the two options mentioned below:

```
if(calAge() >= 21) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.disney.com");
}
```

You could use `window.location.href` as well to achieve the same thing. However, I would strongly recommend reading the answer mentioned above to get a clearer understanding of what is best for your case.